# Select any character string over an NA in an If statement in R

Tags: r, regex, if-statement

I am trying to create a function which will look at two vectors of character labels, and print the appropriate label based on an If statement.  I am running into an issue when one of the vectors is populated by NA.

I'll truncate my function:

```
eventTypepriority=function(a,b) {
  if(is.na(a)) {print(b)}
  if(is.na(b)) {print(a)}
  if(a=="BW"& b=="BW",) {print("BW")}
  if(a=="?BW"& b=="BW") {print("?BW")}
  ...#and so on
}
```

Some data:

```
a=c("Pm", "BW", "?BW")
b=c("PmDP","?BW",NA)

c=mapply(eventTypepriority, a,b, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

The function works fine for the first two, selecting the label I've designated in my if statements.  However, when it gets to the third pair I receive this error:

```
Error in if (a == "?BW" & b == "BW") { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I'm guessing this is because at that place, b=NA, and this is the first if statement, outside of the 'is.na' statements, that need it to ignore missing values.

Is there a way to handle this?  I'd really rather not add conditional statements for every label and NA.  I've also tried:

-is.null (same error message)

-Regular Expressions:

```
if(a==grepl([:print:]) & b==NA) {print(a)}
```

In various formats, including if(a==grepl(:print:)...  No avail. I receive an 'Error: unexpected '[' or whatever character R didn't like first to tell me this is wrong.

All comments and thoughts would be appreciated. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

if all your `if` conditions are exclusives, just call `return()` to avoid checking other conditions when one is met:

```
eventTypepriority=function(a,b) {
  if(is.na(a)) {print(b);return()}
  if(is.na(b)) {print(a);return()}
  if(a=="BW"& b=="BW",) {print("BW");return()}
  if(a=="?BW"& b=="BW") {print("?BW");return()}
  ...#and so on
}
```

Comment: Ah! This works perfectly. I knew I was missing something simple. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `if .. else` statements instead of simply `if`; otherwise, your function will evaluate the 3rd and 4th lines even when one of the values is n/a.

Given you mapply statement, I also assume you want the function to output the corresponding label, not just print it?
In that case

```
eventTypepriority<-function(a,b) {
  if(is.na(a)) b 
  else if(is.na(b)) a
  else if(a=="BW"& b=="BW") "BW"
  else if(a=="?BW"& b=="BW") "?BW"
  else "..."
}

a=c("Pm", "BW", "?BW")
b=c("PmDP","?BW",NA)

c=mapply(eventTypepriority, a,b, USE.NAMES = T)
c
```

returns

```
   Pm    BW   ?BW 
"..." "..." "?BW"
```

If you actually want to just print the label and have your function return something else, you should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  Your way may involve a bit of restructuring, but it's very useful to keep in mind!

To print the labels properly, I've used:

> c=mapply(eventTypepriority, a,b, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
> e=names(c)

Where e becomes the vector I use.

Comment: UPDATE:  This method works much better in the larger function I'm running.  The other method kept returning NAs if only 'b' had data.  Since replacing it with this method, I have solved that issue.  Thanks!!